# Win 10 Projecting to PC does not work

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, miracast

I recently build a new PC and after seeing a video about how simple is projecting PC to different devices I decided to give it a try. Turns out that it is not easy at all.

My setup:

1. Custom build desktop, Ryzen 3, Radeon graphic card, Wifi6 (AX), Win 10 Pro, Bitdefender
2. HP laptop, Intel 8th gen, Intel UHD 620, Wifi5 (AC), Win 10 Home, Bitdefender
3. Lenovo laptop, Intel 8th gen, Intel UHD 620, Wifi5 (AC), Win 10 Pro, Sophos
4. XBox One (1st gen), Wifi4 (N), Wireless display app installed
5. Asus RT-N66U router, Wifi4 (N), 450Mbps
6. UHD Tv, Wifi5 (AC) but connected over 1Gb ethernet directly to router 5

Additional info:

- All devices are on the same network. Wifi is running on 5GHz
- All PCs return `Wireless Display Supported: Yes (Graphics Driver: Yes, Wi-Fi Driver: Yes)` when running `netsh wlan show drivers`
- All PCs are running latest updates of Windows (version 1909), drivers and Antivirus/Firewall (Bitdefender, Sophos)
- During testing, Projecting to this PC setting on both PC 2 and PC 3 were set to Available Everywhere, 
  Ask First Time only, Never require pin
- During testing, PC 2 and PC 3 were usually close to connected device - that seems to be especially important to find XBox???
- PC 1 is on 2nd floor in the house, XBox, Router and TV are on the 1st floor. Overall distance will be 6-8m

What is usually working:

- PC 2 can project to PC 3, XBox and TV
- PC 3 can project to PC 2, XBox and TV
- PC 1 can project to TV
- PC 2 and PC 3 can ping and RDP to PC 1

What is not working:

- PC 1 can't project to PC 2, PC 3 or XBox - it usually does not even find them on the network. TV is found immediately. Turning off Bitdefender (antivirus / firewall) does not help.
- When PC 1 sees PC 2 or XBox, it can't connect anyway.
- PC 1 can't be projected to. System setting tab for "Projecting to this PC" is not present at all. I tried to enable feature in Localhost Group Policy but that didn't help.

Questions:

- How to diagnose if this is network issue?
- How to find why projecting to other device from PC 1 failed (when it actually sees them and tries to connect)?
- Why is Projecting to this PC not available on PC 1?
- How is discovering of wireless devices working? I think I see my neighbour's TV in one part of the house but that is definitely not on my network.

Comment: I initially posted this as an answer, because I thought it would elicit some precisions from the OP, but apparently, this is seriously frowned upon here, to the point that the OP may never get any answer (or comment) at all... So, on with my *comment*, which, hopefully, won't be deleted too: "First off, what do you mean by "projecting"?" (Note: this is my last attempt at helping this guy with his problem. I get quashed, I give up)

Comment: @Didier: Projecting is feature in Win 10 - it is using Miracast to connect to another display remotely. When you cast to TV, it is really just adding wireless monitor but when you cast to another PC or XBox you can also use target device to provide input. That is especially nice on XBox where nothing like RDP exist.